# How can I ignore conversations in Outlook 2011 for Mac?

Tags: ms-office

Outlook for Mac 2011 does not include an "ignore conversation" feature out of the box.  Is there a way to simulate that with other functionality (e.g. categories, rules, plugins, etc)?

What I want to accomplish is to be able to flag a certain *email*  *subject* as something I'd like automatically deleted.  And to do so easily with a click or two.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

After searching over the net and various forums, seems this feature is not present in the outlook on mac.

Comment: Appears still not available in 2020 (version `16.38`)

Answer (score 4):

You can create rules in Outlook 2011.  You should see a rules button with purple arrows on it in the middle of your toolbar.  Or you can go to Tools->Rules...  There you can create rules (and save them to be used easily in the future) to automatically remove emails based on senders, subjects, kind, flags, etc.  Perhaps you can create a rule there that will help you delete unwanted emails.

Comment: it takes far too many clicks to create a rule for this!  i want to easily ignore conversations right from my inbox

Comment: @jlarson You can create a rule one time and then have it saved to apply to future emails.  I don't see another way to do it, immediately.  You could always just click delete and move on.

Comment: "click delete and move on".  That's what I do today.  But often I'll get roped into a thread which gets a ton of back and forth and it gets very annoying to keep getting emails I don't care about.  There are several of these a day and so managing it with a custom rule is a pain.  I hope future outlook-for-mac includes ignore-conversation as a built in feature!

Comment: In Outlook:Mac, there's a "send feedback" item under "help".  Click it and tell Microsoft that you want this feature.  Tell them why you want it and how you would use it.  Be verbose: the better of a case you make, the more likely it is that it will be considered for a future release.  "I want this feature" isn't nearly as useful as "I want this feature because …".

Comment: Not the ideal thing but you can "ignore the conversation" from webmail (Outlook via web browser), if your firm provides one.

Comment: This needs a new rule for every conversation. Is there someway to mark any conversation as Mute/Ignore once and rest of the mails in that thread will follow the rule.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

The feature is missing but you can cast your vote to have it added here:

https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293343-outlook-for-mac/suggestions/8848627-ignore-conversations-button

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Office 365, you can go to Outlook.com, select the thread then at the top, select ... then Ignore:

[image]

Comment: I do not have Office 365, as the question clearly states

Comment: @jlarson What you have installed on your machine does not tell me what subscription you may have. I have Outlook of Mac and outlook.com.

Comment: @pyb what is installed on someone's machine also does not tell you what all exists in stores that they could go out and buy, or use on their friend's computer, or code themself... this Answer is off-topic.

Comment: @cellepo Some users of Outlook for Mac 2011 have access to outlook.com. Your analogy is absurd. Outlook for Mac and outlook.com are both Microsoft products, it is reasonable to think some people have access to both. Besides, jlarson did not accept the other answer "this feature is not present in the outlook on mac", or any other answer.

Comment: I can understand how this look like an irrelevant answer, I suggest you flag my answer as such. If it gets deleted I will add my own Q&A.

Comment: This answer is very relevant to many people searching for the question though. Please don't delete it.